# Make SharePoint responsive - Bootstrap or media query?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to make my SharePoint site responsive 
so that it can be viewed easily in ipad, iphone, tablets, etc.

What is the best way to do it with Bootstrap or media query.

Any suggestion will be great help.

Comment: Depends on design , DO you have many pages please use Bootstrap

Comment: Äh Bootstrap is making use of media queries to implement it's responsive layouts.

Answer (score 7):

I was in the situation to choose which one i would use to implement a responsive design in SP2013 and so I collected **pro's** and **con's** foreach technology.

---

### Device Channels

Yes I'm talking about `Device Channels` even when they are not mentioned in the question, because they can deliver the best performance and optimizability for the enduser and the client - in my opinion :)

**Pro**

- individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
- -- no need for hiding or removing incompatible elements
- -- faster because you just load things you really need
- -- faster because you will likely have less `CSS/JS and HTML`
- -- faster because you can use optimized code foreach device
- -- better you can better point out which channel has errors and changes dont affect the other channels

**Con**

- individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
- -- you have to append changes to each masterpage
- -- more work to accomplish the same result (in general)
- -- redundancy
- bound to `User Agent Strings`
- growing diversity of devices
- -- may equals growing diversity of masterpages >> work

---

### Bootstrap

**Pro**

- mighty, easy to use framework
- -- a lot of documentation
- -- fast results
- -- if you like it - all the Bootstrap styles
- there are already projects using it so you may dont have to build it from scratch
- -- http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/

**Con**

- Bootstrap is a huge framework and has 8000+ lines of code in the unminified `CSS` and `JS` files
- -- 2 requests extra for ~ 130kb & 30kb
- -- a lot of styles and script for your browser to handle
- Bootstrap is not build for use in SharePoint
- -- it's overwriting SharePoint styles which makes some features (`ComposedLooks` for ex.) less valuable
- -- there are a lot of custom `CSS` needed to make it work seamless with SharePoint
- SharePoint has it's own weird way to do things and that interferes with BootStrap
- -- tons of `CSS`
- -- tons of `JS`
- -- tons of `HTML Attributes`

---

### Media Queries

**Pro**

- only necessary `CSS`
- no `JS` if you dont wan't to
- you can create your own layout
- with `response.js` even in IE6 working
- you can easily separate which features should be available in certain screen sizes

**Con**

- several sets of `CSS` depending on the number of `Breakpoints`
- every feature needs to be developed by yourself
- it's not easy to write generic code that can process every SP2013 Page
- -- it depends on the complexity of the content shown. I write about 150 lines of `CSS` that created a mobile view for publishing pages that contained the navigation and content, but no features like editing, etc.
- -- if the client's want every feature on his smartphone, there is a hell lot of work and testing needed. (Plus who the hell wants to do that on their phone?)

---

### Conclusion

I'm not sure yet (and it would be awesome to get a lot of feedback to my results), but i tend to use `Media Queries`. Why ? Well SharePoint has it's own way to handle desktop users and i wouldn't customize that build in functionality if not explicit ordered. On the other hand SharePoint doesn't provide a real UI for smartphones. I don't want to use BootStrap because it contains a lot of styling which will produce problems in branded environments. And I won't use `Device Channels` because of the downsides.

---

What do you think ? Are there important aspects I'm missing ? Are there other solutions which are better suited for realizing this ?

Comment: A very comprehensive and complete evaluation of responsive design in general. I would add a recommendation for Foundation by ZURB which I personally work with and find to be a great in-between Bootstrap (which is very rigid in it's styles) and media queries (which can be very labor intensive to build from the ground up).